# How do I send a video from a user to Amazon S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am just getting started with using AWS, and I found plenty of information online for how to send file to an S3 bucket using node, but they only work if the file I'm uploading is in on my computer.  How do I make an app that will allow a user to upload a video and have it sent to my Amazon S3 bucket?  Any help would be appreciated, even if its just linking to helpful docs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a one-time write ticket to AWS S3 bucket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986019/how-to-implement-a-one-time-write-ticket-to-aws-s3-bucket)

Comment: Where's the video coming from?  It's best if you sign a URL so the user can just upload directly.

Comment: The video is coming from an android app, so it's a video on the users phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html) is an example from Amazon. You should do this from the front end directly to S3. If you transfer your files through your server it will not scale past a couple of hundred users.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999551/simple-upload-to-s3-from-android) answer.